# Get file name which is currently open in windows directory

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I am developing file monitoring application in WPF and C#. Now i want to monitor files from given directory while my application running in background. I am going to provide directory name at the first time. Then i want to monitor files from that directory whether they are open or currently accessing or modified.

Is it possible in WPF? Is there any link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably may want to write a [windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.aspx) using [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

FileSystemWatcher is what you want, check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter.aspx

Here is an example: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sbappdev/thread/229fc072-a149-4713-8e20-9b5d6eecee71